# GetUpperBound vs UBound for speed

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance

Which is faster? I've tried googling and couldn't find anything even remotely helpful to settle this on my own. Best I got was this simple DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i6Yx6R

Comment: You tried googling, but did you tested them?

Comment: There is this class called `StopWatch` you can use it for testing how long processes take.

Comment: Another **Which is Faster** kind of question. [Please read this](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UBound` just calls `Array.GetUpperBound` internally, so their implementation is near identical:

```
Public Function UBound(ByVal Array As System.Array, Optional ByVal Rank As Integer = 1) As Integer

        If (Array Is Nothing) Then
            Throw VbMakeException(New ArgumentNullException(GetResourceString(ResID.Argument_InvalidNullValue1, "Array")), vbErrors.OutOfBounds)

        ElseIf (Rank < 1) OrElse (Rank > Array.Rank) Then
            Throw New RankException(GetResourceString(ResID.Argument_InvalidRank1, "Rank"))

        End If

        Return Array.GetUpperBound(Rank - 1)

    End Function
```

This was obtained from Microsoft's [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Information.vb,163).

The difference between the two is sure to be almost immeasurable, but I would suspect `UBound` would be ever so slightly slow since it does some bounds checking, first.

In reality, because their actual implementations are the same, I would use whichever you are more comfortable using stylistically.